# How do i update datagrid in real time if the database is updated with new row?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagrid, logic

I have a database that grabs information from app1 and then that data is added in the app2. but this only happens when i run the app2.

I want app2 to be able to grab data at any time if database gets data from app1. Is there a way to make a database watcher which can notify my app2 saying there's a new row added to the database and grab that info and post it to app2.
Following is the method that adds info to app2 inside the datagrid.

```
public static void AddData(DataGrid datagrid)
        {
            collection.Clear();
            using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select req_status, req_date_time, resp_user_name From TH_request where req_status = 'N'", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            collection.Add(new DataObject()
                            {
                                A = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["req_date_time"]),
                                B = Convert.ToString(reader["resp_user_name"]),
                                C = Convert.ToString(reader["req_status"]),
                                D = respUserName
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            datagrid.ItemsSource = collection;
            DisplayName();
        }
```

Comment: Ypu could use a BackgroundWorker which is watching the database. You could also use another tiny app which looks for changes and uses a message queue to notify other apps.

Comment: can you give a tiny example of BackgroundWorker(). How does it work? I am fairly new to these things.

Comment: The MSDN examples are pretty good, look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

Comment: You have a choice iof (more or less) tight polling (which is what developer10214 suggested )  or finding a DB which allows you to write a trigger that call a function on your application. The former will put strain on the DB the latter is somewhat hard to do..